# Is it possible to process equality in a std::set comparator?

Tags: c++, c++11, set, comparator, predicate

I am sorry if the title isn't very descriptive, I was having a hard time figuring out how to name this question. This is pretty much the first time I need to use a set, though I've been using maps forever.

I don't think it is possible, but I need to ask. I would like to perform a specific action on a struct when I add it to my std::set, but only if equality is true.

For example, I can use a list and then sort() and unique() the list. In my predicate, I can do as I wish, since I will get the result if 2 values are equal.

Here is a quick example of what my list predicate looks like:

```
bool markovWeightOrdering (unique_ptr<Word>& w1, unique_ptr<Word>& w2) {
        if (w1->word_ == w2->word_) {
                w1->weight_++;
                return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve a similar result, while using a std::set for the obvious gain in performance (and simplicity), since my container needs to be unique anyways? Thank you for any help or guidance, it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

element in `set` are immutable, so you cannot modify them.

if you use `set` with pointer (or similar), the pointed object may be modified (but care to not modify the order). `std::set::insert` returns a `pair` with `iterator` and a boolean to tell if element has been inserted, so you may do something like:

```
auto p = s.insert(make_unique<Word>("test"));
if (p.second == false) {
    (*p.first)->weight += 1;
}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/KjExG8)

Comment: So if I order my set using the weight... Than basically what I am doing is really really wrong. Then is there another container that is a search tree, which I can modify the values inside? Or am I dreaming here? :)

Comment: You may be interested by [multi_index in boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

Comment: No, stop it with the Boost please.

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating a compare operator is likely a bad idea.
You might use a std::set with a predicate, instead:

```
struct LessWord
{
    bool operator () (const std::unique_ptr<Word>& w1, const std::unique_ptr<Word>& w2) {
        return w1->key < w2->key;
    }
};
typedef std::set<std::unique_ptr<Word>, LessWord> word_set;
```

Than you test at insert if the word is existing and increment the weight:

```
word_set words;
std::unique_ptr<Word> word_ptr;
auto insert = words.insert(word_ptr);
if( ! insert.second)
    ++(insert.first->get()->weight_);
```

Note: Doing this is breaking const correctness, logically. A set element is immutable, but the unique_ptr enables modifications (even a fatal modification of key values).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I marked the other one simply because it was more clear what insert does.